# Process only certain partitions of cube

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2014, ssas-tabular

I have a cube that is partitioned by year. I want to do a full process to only the last couple of years, as only data from this period can have changed, been added or deleted. I am unable to figure out how to choose that only certain partitions should be processed. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Partitions are defined on a Measuregroup.  If your entire cube is time-partitioned, that sounds as though every measuregroup that's sliced by the Time dimension is time-partitioned.  (You may have only one measuregroup in your cube, though).

You can see partitions in the "Partitions" tab of the Cube design window.  You can process partitions here (manually, at the dev stage), or from SSMS, or by generating an XMLA script to be run on a scheduled basis.  Essentially what you do is process the partition rather than the entire measuregroup.

Answer (score -1):

If you use SSIS, there is a task called Analysis Services Processing Task. In the Processing Settings of this task you can select the kinds of objects you want to process, including one or more partitions for a table.